# Obtain every nth row of filtered records

Tags: excel, copy, row, filtering

I'm looking for information on how to copy nth rows of records from one excel sheet to the next, and now I am wondering if there is a way to do this for filtered data (i.e. I have 400 students enrolled at school, and I want every 15th male whose parents have not graduated from college (flags have been created for both gender and parent education, which I am using to filter on). Are there any ideas on how to do this? If not, I could just use the offset function for each combination of variables I am filtering on, but that's over 30-40 combinations if I did my math right. Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few standard formulas used for retrieving the *first, second, third, etc* set of values that match criteria. I prefer a standard formula model using the [INDEX function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/index-function-HP010342608.aspx) and [SMALL function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SMALL-function-4050a82e-659a-4ef6-a970-c963a6f69c29). By throwing a little maths at the increment to change it from *1, 2, 3 ...* to *1, 16, 31, 46, ...* you should be able to achieve your offset results. In the following example image, I've used a stagger of *4* rather than *15* in order to accommodate sample data vertically while still producing more than a single result.

[image: Every 15 matches]

The formula in F2 is,

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A$2:A$999, SMALL(INDEX(ROW($1:$998)+((C$2:C$999<>"M")+(D$2:D$999<>"N"))*1E+99, , ), 1+(ROW(1:1)-1)*4)), "")
```

For your purposes the 4 in `1+(ROW(1:1)-1)*4` will need to be changed to 15.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A$2:A$999, SMALL(INDEX(ROW($1:$998)+((C$2:C$999<>"M")+(D$2:D$999<>"N"))*1E+99, , ), 1+(ROW(1:1)-1)*15)), "")
```

Fill down as necessary.

Once you have retrieved a unique identifier, the remainder can be retrieved with a simple [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65).